# mutate() error while kniting Kaggle R Notebook

Tags: r, markdown, knitr, kaggle, mutate

I have created a Kaggle notebook using R code and R Markdown together. I am facing this error-

**Error in UseMethod("mutate"): no applicable method for 'mutate' applied to an object of class "character"
Traceback:

1. dplyr::mutate(daily_activities$day_of_the_week <- weekdays(daily_activities$activity_date))**

-whenever I am trying to run all the codes together.

The codes are working perfectly individually.
I simply wanted to use R codes and R markdown together. Instead of using R Markdown directly, I used R notebook, and then this happened.

The link to my Kaggle notebook is [here](https://www.kaggle.com/code/anshikakashyap12/smart-device-usage-data-analysis).

Please help me sort this issue as I am struggling since morning with this.

[Also, according to what I have understood - I am thinking that there is a problem of using R MarkDown and R code together, maybe I have not used them together correctly. Kindly correct me if I am wrong. Thanks.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume it has nothing do with R Markdown.

I created a kaggle account and downloaded your data `dailyActivity_merged.csv`. For reproducibility I have uploaded the first ten rows.

After this line

```
daily_activities$activity_date <- as.POSIXct(daily_activities$ActivityDate, 
                                             format="%m/%d/%Y", 
                                             tz = Sys.timezone())
```

consider to change your code to either of the following

1. using `{dplyr}` syntax

```
daily_activities |>
  dplyr::mutate(DayOfWeek = weekdays(activity_date))
```

2. or using `base R`

```
daily_activities$DayOfWeek <- weekdays(daily_activities$activity_date)
```

You may change the variable names accordingly.

Data

```
daily_activities10 <- structure(list(Id = c(1503960366, 1503960366, 1503960366, 1503960366, 
                                            1503960366, 1503960366), ActivityDate = c("4/12/2016", "4/13/2016", 
                                                                                      "4/14/2016", "4/15/2016", "4/16/2016", "4/17/2016"), TotalSteps = c(13162L, 
                                                                                                                                                          10735L, 10460L, 9762L, 12669L, 9705L), TotalDistance = c(8.5, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                   6.96999979019165, 6.73999977111816, 6.28000020980835, 8.15999984741211, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                   6.48000001907349), TrackerDistance = c(8.5, 6.96999979019165, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          6.73999977111816, 6.28000020980835, 8.15999984741211, 6.48000001907349
                                                                                                                                                                                                                   ), LoggedActivitiesDistance = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), VeryActiveDistance = c(1.87999999523163, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             1.57000005245209, 2.44000005722046, 2.14000010490417, 2.71000003814697, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             3.19000005722046), ModeratelyActiveDistance = c(0.550000011920929, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             0.689999997615814, 0.400000005960464, 1.25999999046326, 0.409999996423721, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             0.779999971389771), LightActiveDistance = c(6.05999994277954, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         4.71000003814697, 3.91000008583069, 2.82999992370605, 5.03999996185303, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         2.50999999046326), SedentaryActiveDistance = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        0), VeryActiveMinutes = c(25L, 21L, 30L, 29L, 36L, 38L), FairlyActiveMinutes = c(13L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         19L, 11L, 34L, 10L, 20L), LightlyActiveMinutes = c(328L, 217L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            181L, 209L, 221L, 164L), SedentaryMinutes = c(728L, 776L, 1218L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          726L, 773L, 539L), Calories = c(1985L, 1797L, 1776L, 1745L, 1863L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          1728L)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Thank You @Friede !! The 'base R' solution worked for me. 

When I used 'mutate(daily_activities$day_of_the_week <- weekdays(daily_activities$activity_date))' in RStudio(desktop), it worked, but in Kaggle Notebook it didn't. Can you please educate me why that happened ?

Comment: Assuming there is no typo in your code, perhaps due to the fact that mutate is not loaded in Kaggle?